# Getting started with Newspeak

Tags: newspeak

What are the good resources for [Newspeak](http://newspeaklanguage.org/) programming language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start with [Newspeak 101](http://bracha.org/newspeak-101.pdf) and ask questions in the [Help forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/newspeaklanguage) There are some nice examples [here](http://langexplr.blogspot.com/search/label/newspeak) (I suggest you start with the Twitter Client at the bottom).

Answer (score 10):

You probably know this place, but if not, make sure to follow Gilad Bracha's blog, http://gbracha.blogspot.com/

I'd suggest to read this, even if you're not interested in Newspeak. This guy rocks.